# Assignment in Data.table using .SD Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, max, data.table, time-series

I have a datatable DT with n variables V1,...,Vn (each of these variable consists of m time series) indicated by a key called id_ts. I would like to apply a function f on the first element of each time series for a selection of variables Vi1,...,Vik i\in {1,...,n} and k

```
n <- 4L; m <- 2L; k <- 2L; t <- 5L

DT <- data.table(id_ts = rep(1:m,(rep(t,m))), 
                 data.table(sapply(1:n, function(i){rnorm(t*m)})), key = "id_ts")

# P is a data.table of same number of varialbes as the number of vars in DT (that is 4 here)
P <- data.table(t(c(0.45,2.345,-0.245,4.245)))     

# index for first element of each time series
Ind_rows <- seq.int(from = 1L, to = t*m, by = t)
# index for the variables (here V1 and V3)
Ind_cols <- c(1L,3L)

# function
f <- function(x,p){pmax(x,p)}

# the assignment of .SD gives me an error
DT[Ind_rows, .SD := mapply(f, .SD, P[,Ind_cols,with=F], SIMPLIFY=F), .SDcols = Ind_cols+1]

# Error:
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, Ind_rows, `:=`(.SD, mapply(f,  : 
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

or EDIT:

```
DT[Ind_rows, names(.SD) := mapply(f, .SD, P[,Ind_cols,with=F], SIMPLIFY=F), .SDcols = Ind_cols+1]

# Error:
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, Ind_rows, `:=`(names(.SD), mapply(f, .SD,  : 
LHS of := isn't column names ('character') or positions ('integer' or 'numeric')
```

Does anyone have a solution to this error. If anyone has a more efficient solution to the problem as a whole this would also be welcome. 
For example, I would not need the whole mapply if there would be a function where I could take the max between each columns and an entry in a vector, ie

```
P <- c(0.45,2.345,-0.245,4.245)
pmax(DT[Ind_rows, Ind_cols+1, with = F], P)
```

taking the max between each column and entry in P, but this does not work with pmax of course. 
Of course, I could use a for loop over the nr of columns/variables but that would be slow.

Thanks for you help!!!

Comment: Please fix your code. You use `Ind_rows` and `Ind_row`, `Ind_cols` and `Ind_col`. Which leads to errors.

Comment: You can't assign to `.SD` if this is what you are trying to do. `.SD` is locked. Your code, if would work, will just create a new column called `.SD`. Try `DT <- data.table(A = 1:5, B = 6:10) ; DT[, .SD := 4]` for instance.

Comment: However, you can assign to `names(.SD)`.

Comment: @Roland: I tried with the names(.SD) but that gives me an error as well. (I edited the text above)

Comment: @Roland: The following, although less elegant, seems to work:

    DT[Ind_rows, names(DT)[Ind_cols+1] := mapply(f, .SD, P[,Ind_cols,with=F], SIMPLIFY=F), .SDcols = Ind_cols+1]

Why does this work, though and not names(.SD)?

But how about the overall question regarding the pmax?